# rows value from mysql select max query returns undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to look for the max id value in my table so i used the following query

```
   connection.query ('SELECT * FROM report', 
        function (err,rows){
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!rows.length)  var idTest = 0

        else {
            connection.query ('SELECT MAX(id) FROM report ' , 
                function (err,results , fields){

                console.log (results)
                console.log (fields)
                console.log (results[0].id)  // returns undefined
                console.log (results.id) // returns undefined
                });
        }

});
```

for console.log (results) I get :

> [ { 'MAX(id)': 2 } ]

but somehow i cant retrieve the 2 number
Any suggestions why ?

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT MAX(id) as id` ?